# How does 'Wunderwaffen' end?

Tags: comics, wunderwaffen

How did the series “*Wunderwaffen*” end?

Issues 1 through 16 are online, but the remaining two are only in French.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Does this comic contain any science fiction or fantasy elements? At first glance, it doesn't seem to, in which case, this question would be off-topic here.

Comment: The comic is partially sci fi, it has floating islands!

Comment: @F1Krazy - *In the summer of 1946, the Japanese have been beaten but World War II continues in Europe after the Normandy landings failed on June 6th, 1944.
Completely revolutionary jet planes, the Wunderwaffen, or Wonder Weapons, now efficiently defend Germany.*

Comment: Amazon lists five volumes after Vol. 16. The [most recent](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wunderwaffen-T21-Maza/dp/2302095359/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=wunderwaffen&qid=1695996540&sr=8-3) is dated May 2023 and doesn't appear to be 'The End' as it ends on a cliffhanger...

Comment: Valorum, thank you, that was helpful